# SPARK - Why the spark job duration is not equal to the sum of each stage duration?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

A spark job consist of a collection of several stages...

I was expecting that the executing duration of a job would be equal , or at least similar, to the sum of the duration of each stage.

However, I am getting a huge discrepancy:  1,3 min X  3,2 seconds

Is it normal/acceptable?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, the job execution time is a wall clock time

It means that the time is still measured while stages are not actually computed: The cluster may be busy doing anything else between the stages of your job

This may also work in the opposite direction: While multiple stages are executed in parallel, the sum of stage execution time may be greater then job execution time.

Comment: if a database read operation is inside the spark job, is the time necessary to fetch all data computed or not in the stage duration?