# What does spark stage time stands for and what does the executor task gc time stands for?

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have three questions here.

1. first one is that my spark job contains only one stage, and the job time / stage time is show as the pic below. Job time is the wall time from my insights, and here the stage time is almost half of the job time, what does it stands for.

> *Spark Job Time*
>   [image: SparkJobTime]
>   *Spark Stage Time*
>   [image: SparkStageTime]

2. The seconds question is that GC Time is too large compares with Task Time, what does the gc time stands for.  I means whether minor/full gc included, whether stop-the-world included?
   [image: SparkExecutors]

> Remarks
>   what dose the job do: read hbase -> do little process -> save as parquet on hdfs
>   data size: ~ 40T
>   executors num: 180
>   executor heap mem: 16G
>   executor overhead mem: 4G
>   executor jvm: oracle 64bit
>   executor jvm args: `-Xms16g -Xmx16g -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32m -XX:+UseCompressedOops`

3. The executor's gc is so unnormal, and I am investigate it, info below is what I found. I want to know how to optimize JVM args, it seems full gc will take a long time(greater than 20 seconds).

   > Heap Mem Usage
   >   [image: HeapMemUsage]
   >   G1 Eden Space
   >   [image: G1EdenSpace]
   >   G1 Survivor Space
   >   [image: G1SurvivorSpace]
   >   G1 Old Space
   >   [image: G1OldSpace]
   >   GC statistics
   >   6 minutes on G1 Young Generation (1,034 collections)
   >   22 minutes on G1 Old Generation (46 collections)

> And let's see what heap looks like(I dumped one heap)
>   Sorry for no picture here, I did not save it yesterday when I analysis it with Eclipse Memory Analysis, but we could make sure that their are three big Hash Map Object which consumes nearly 10G memory(These three guy are static var and can not be free-ed, and this is not bug! it really needs these three big hash map.)

Thanks.

Comment: Stage time stands for time taken to complete processing a stage in the spark job. It includes all tasks related to that stage. The tasks GC time is time taken while processing task. It includes major and minor GC.

Comment: @deo so, is GC time included for stage time?

Comment: Yes, but GC time is for individual tasks where as stage time is the total time for all parallel tasks from start to finish.

Comment: @deo Could you tell me why the stage time is ~ half of the job time for their only one job and one stage in the job. What did the job doing on the rest time. Thank you.

Comment: did u resolce this btw?

Comment: Below answers might help you in understanding this if answer is not found till now : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466265/spark-why-the-spark-job-duration-is-not-equal-to-the-sum-of-each-stage-duratio?rq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263270/what-is-the-concept-of-application-job-stage-and-task-in-spark?rq=1